# Install PHP 7.4 PDO driver for PostgreSQL on Centos 7.6

Tags: postgresql, pdo, centos7

I get the error from PDO when trying to connect to PostgreSQL:

```
Database Connection Error: could not find driver
```

I ran command to install driver:

```
yum install php7.4-pgsql
systemctl restart httpd
```

Still did not work.  I found another possible driver:

```
yum install php72w-pdo
systemctl restart httpd
```

Still did not work. Checking phpinfo() page does not show PDO driver for PostgreSQL installed, and checking has no output for pgsql.

```
php -m | grep pgsql
```

I also tried installing PostgreSQL on the server, but I don't think I need since the connection is remote server.  I also tried other tutorials but most are for PHP 5 and not for PHP 7.4. They said use command:

```
yum install php-pgsql
```

But this command will give me error for package conflict and list of required:

```
Error: Package: php-pgsql-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-48.el7
           Installed: php-pdo-7.4.11-1.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php74)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 7.4.11-1.el7.remi
           Available: php-pdo-5.4.16-48.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-48.el7
...
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

However, I don't think these options should be necessary for Centos 7.4, PHP 7.4.

I can connect from MacOs development environment, but not from the Centos server.

What should I do to install the driver for PDO PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had multiple versions of PHP enabled.
Here is solution to disable all except for the one you want:

```
php -v
PHP 7.4.24 (cli) (built: Sep 21 2021 11:23:11) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

Check which version you are running (example 7.4)

```
yum-config-manager --disable 'remi-php*'
yum-config-manager --enable   remi-php74
```

Then install is easy:

```
yum install php-pdo_pgsql
systemctl restart httpd
```